# Can I easily replace spring-boot-starter by spring-boot to avoid use of spring-boot-starter-parent?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I want to use spring-boot-starter, but that means I have to use the "spring-boot-starter-parent" pom and cannot use the company wide used root pom.

Spring-boot-starter is a huge advantage when it comes to manage dependecy and plugin that go together. But that contradict the advantage of our company wide used root pom.

Are there further advantages of using spring-boot-starter? 
Is there an easy way to only use spring-boot without spring-boot-starter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not want to use the `spring-boot-starter-parent`, you can still keep the benefit of the dependency management (but not the plugin management) by using a `scope=import` dependency, as follows:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent) you can find an appropriate section in Spring Documentation with more details.

Comment: Trying this I end up with this warning:

 'dependencies.dependency.scope' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is 'import'. @ line 26, column 17 It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

Comment: @fancyJaneDo you are still referencing the 'spring-boot-starter-parent' artifact. You need to use the 'spring-boot-*dependencies*' artifact, per this answer, and the linked Spring documentation

Answer (score 1):

Add needed version of `spring-boot-starter-parent` as the parent to your company's root pom.xml file.

- This way it is `spring-boot` that manages all the dependencies for all of your projects.
- Your Company's parent-pom can have its own `<dependencyManagement>` to override and manage any internal or third-party dependencies.
- The `plugin management` is cleaner this way. You can define your own stages on project and parent level.